# What happens to the rider if a mount dies?

Tags: dnd-4e, mounted-combat

Does he fall prone or is he simply placed in an adjacent square?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***The rider falls prone in an adjacent square***

From the DMG and the Rules Compendium<sup>[[ddi]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=582)</sup>

> **Falling Prone:** If the mount falls prone, the rider is dismounted and falls prone in an unoccupied space of the rider’s choice adjacent to the now-prone mount. However, if the mount is flying when it is knocked prone, it instead falls. The rider isn’t dismounted unless the mount lands and falls prone itself. A rider who is knocked prone can immediately make a saving throw. On a roll of 9 or lower, the rider is dismounted and falls prone in an unoccupied space of the rider’s choice adjacent to the mount. On a roll of 10 or higher, the rider is neither dismounted nor knocked prone. A rider who voluntarily drops prone falls prone in an unoccupied space of the rider’s choice adjacent to the mount.

Comment: Wait, no damage?

Comment: No damage is called for under the rules as written (other than that required by the falling distance, in the case of a flying mount.)

Comment: Wasn't sure if the mount dying counted as falling prone. Thanks for the clarification!